# C Reading records from text file in C using structure

Tags: c, struct, stdin, file-handling, file-pointer

I am trying to extract records from a text file named lib.txt. My program is a very simple library based management program where I will have to print all books by a given publisher or department.
My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Books
{
    char name[100];
    char author[100];
    char publisher[100];
    double price;
    char branch[100];
};

typedef struct Books Books;

void main()
{
    int a = 0,b=0,ch,i;
    char *pb = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    Books *bk;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("lib.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\n Error to open the file \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if(feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        char c;
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            a++;
        }
    }
    a++;
    bk = (Books *)malloc(a*sizeof(Books));
    while(fread(&bk[b],sizeof(Books),1,fp))  //Even tried individual character extraction but it is not working
    {
        b++;
        if(b==a)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",bk[i].name);
    }
    printf("1. Display books supplied by a particular publisher \n");
    printf("2. Display books in a particular branch \n");
    printf("3. Exit");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            printf("Enter the name of publisher \n");
            scanf(" %s",pb);
            printf("\nName\tAuthor\tPublisher\tPrice\tBranch\n");
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(bk[i].publisher,pb)==0)
                {
                    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2lf\t%s \n",bk[i].name,bk[i].author,bk[i].publisher,bk[i].price,bk[i].branch);
                }
            }
            fflush(pb);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printf("Enter the name of branch \n");
            scanf(" %s",pb);
            printf("\nName\tAuthor\tPublisher\tPrice\tBranch\n");
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(bk[i].publisher,pb)==0)
                {
                    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2lf\t%s \n",bk[i].name,bk[i].author,bk[i].publisher,bk[i].price,bk[i].branch);
                }
            }
            fflush(pb);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            return;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("Invalid choice");
        }
    }
    free(bk);
    free(pb);
    fclose(fp);

    getch();
}
```

The file lib.txt contains the following lines in same order as shown below:

```
Abc1    A1  P1  23.0    B1
Abc2    A2  P2  23.0    B2
Abc3    A3  P3  23.0    B3
Abc4    A4  P2  23.0    B4
Abc5    A5  P2  23.0    B5
Abc6    A6  P6  23.0    B6
Abc7    A7  P2  23.0    B7
```

Oh and they are seperated by tabs. Even tried with spaces but no change. The program is compiling fine but not generating desired output. Can anyone please please help?
Edit: Even tried individual character extraction and then splitting into substrings but failed. Please help

Comment: Does "not generating desired output" mean no output, garbled output, misaligned output, crashing or...?

Comment: There are two compiler warnings (two same occurrences) from `fflush(pb);` which is `'function': incompatible types - from 'char *' to 'FILE *'`

Comment: ... so increase the warning level, as this is a serious error.

Comment: regarding output it is like it is printing everything excluding the records

Comment: It seems as if my code is unable to extract those records

Comment: `if feof(fp)` is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Yes; `int c; while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { if(c == '\n') { a++; } }` Note the type returned by `fgetc()` is not `char`.

Comment: Ok I have tried but it is still generating the same undesired output. Please help

Comment: @214_SuryaMajumder Try opening `lib.txt` in a decent text editor and see if there are tabs or spaces. Maybe they are mixed.

Comment: @Zakk I tried using notepad and gave tabs but it is still not working. Please help

Comment: @214_SuryaMajumder OK I will write an answer.

Comment: You are at the end of the file when you start reading

Comment: @stark can you please help me

Comment: You neeed to rewind the file to read it again.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are doing `fread` on a text file; it will overlay the `struct Books`. Since you don't have enough information, it will complete a partial read of one `name` (happily including the tabs), and then complete. Probably want the parsing of `fscanf` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

First, define some functions to help you read input (you can use them in other programs as well):

```c
int readint(int *i)
{
    char buffer[255];
    if (!fgets(buffer, 255, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "stdin error\n");
        return 0; // failed
    }

    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", i) != 1)
        return 0; // failed
    
    return 1; // success
}

char *readstr(char *str, int size)
{
    if (!fgets(str, size, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "stdin error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Then your `main()`:

```c
int main()
{
    // 1. Attempt to open file
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FILE *fp = fopen("lib.txt", "r");
    if(!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error to open the file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    // 2. Read file text
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int lines_count = 7; // Depends on how many lines you have
    Books *bk = malloc(lines_count * sizeof(*bk));
    if (!bk) {
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    
    char line[255];
    int i = 0;
    
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove \n read by fgets()
        
        char name[100];
        char author[100];
        char publisher[100];
        double price;
        char branch[100];
        
        int ret = sscanf(line, "%99[^\t]\t%99[^\t]\t%99[^\t]\t%lf\t%99[^\t]", name, author, publisher, &price, branch);
        if (ret != 5) {
            printf("Line %d is problematic.\n", i+1);
        }

        strcpy(bk[i].name, name);
        strcpy(bk[i].author, author);
        strcpy(bk[i].publisher, publisher);
        bk[i].price = price;
        strcpy(bk[i].branch, branch);
        
        i++;
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    // 3. User input
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    printf("1. Display books supplied by a particular publisher\n");
    printf("2. Display books in a particular branch\n");
    printf("3. Exit");
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Enter your choice: ");
    int ch;
    readint(&ch); // Ignored error checking for the sake of simplicity
    
    char pb[100];
    
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter the name of publisher: ");
        readstr(pb, sizeof(pb));
        
        printf("\nName\tAuthor\tPublisher\tPrice\tBranch\n");
        for(i = 0; i < lines_count; i++)
            if(!strcmp(bk[i].publisher, pb))
                printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2lf\t%s \n", bk[i].name, bk[i].author, bk[i].publisher, bk[i].price, bk[i].branch);

        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Enter the name of branch: ");
        readstr(pb, sizeof(pb));
        
        printf("\nName\tAuthor\tPublisher\tPrice\tBranch\n");
        
        for(i = 0; i < lines_count; i++)
            if(!strcmp(bk[i].branch, pb))
                printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2lf\t%s \n",bk[i].name, bk[i].author, bk[i].publisher ,bk[i].price, bk[i].branch);
        
        break;
    
    case 3:
        return 0;
    
    default:
        printf("Invalid choice\n");
    }
    
    free(bk);
}
```

Make sure `lib.txt` contains tabs, not spaces. You should verify if your editor is replacing tabs with spaces.

---

### Few things to consider:

1. `main()` should always return `int`, not `void`.
2. Use `fgets()` to read input from the user, and `sscanf()` to parse it. **You should avoid using** `scanf()` **as much as you can.**

Comment: thank you very much. You don't know how much this helped me. And thanks for giving those advises as well. They really helped. Thank you.

Comment: can you please explain to me what is the use of sscanf() in buffer for integer?

Comment: Ok sorry to disturb you I got it @Zakk. Thank you very much.

Comment: Umm sorry to disturb you @Zakk but readstr is giving error conflicting types

Comment: This is much closer to what you want: the input is read by `fgets` line by line into a buffer and then `sscanf` is used to parse that. To be robust, I'd also warn if the line doesn't fit in the line buffer. The trouble with `[f]scanf` is it doesn't delineate between whitespace, which you need here.